# Struts MessageResources to a more general solution at Business Layer

Tags: java, internationalization, struts

I need your help on a general design question...

I wonder if someone has already had the problem to migrate an old Struts 1.2 project with all the business logic in the struts action to a more modular and layered project. I started writing the BO layer moving logic from Actions, but I'm wondering how to manage the internationalization of Biz messages without using struts MessageResources, that would "contaminate" the new business layer with struts classes. For example when I need to send an email, the old code is:

```
    //MessageResources resources comes from org.apache.struts.action.Action.getResources(HttpServletRequest request)
    mailServer.sendEmailTo(user.getEmail(), resources.getMessage(locale, "mail.title"),
    resources.getMessage(locale, "mail.activation.email", param));
```

Is there a clever way to do this in a Struts web application?
Thanks and sorry if the question is unclear or too general...

Comment: Use normal resources? E.g., use what Java already provides you?

Comment: I would lose struts MessageResources functionality... and don't want to reinvent the wheel... I was thinking at some open source library with similar functionality but not binded to this old MVC framework?

Comment: I'm not sure which functionality you're referring to.

Comment: Uhm... Maybe I just need ResourceBundle...

Comment: I found this utility class that really fit my needs, thanks Dave, at the end it is just to use stuff Java already gives to us ;) http://murygin.wordpress.com/2010/04/23/parameter-substitution-in-resource-bundles/